# Swift 3.0: Timer not firing for target other than self

Tags: ios, swift, selector, swift3

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5.0, target:self.notificationView, selector: #selector(NotificationView.self.timerFired(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

func timerFired(_ timer: Timer) {
        print("Timer Fired")
}
```

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_SwiftValue timerFired:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc0baf46f60'

I don't understand where is wrong? If target is self then everything works fine.

Comment: Perhaps this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39622721/how-initialize-a-timer-inside-a-custom-class-in-swift?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this part of your error message:

> [_SwiftValue timerFired:]

`timerFired:` is an Objective-C style notation of the selector. Seems your `#selector(...)` is working. (Though not recommended...)

`_SwiftValue` is a class name of the object being the target of the selector. This means your target `target:self.notificationView` is converted to `_SwiftValue`.

This may happen when you declare your `notificationView` as Optional or implicitly unwrapped Optional. If so, try this:

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5.0, target: self.notificationView!, selector: #selector(NotificationView.timerFired(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```

(Please do not miss the `!` after `self.notificationView`.)

Comment: Thank you. This is silly mistake very not silly actually. It worked.

Comment: @PawanKumarSingh, compiler should detect this sort of mistakes and warn us. Many developers are suffering with this `_SwiftValue` thing. You can call it a bug and send a bug report to [Apple](http://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your `selector` syntax it will be like this.

```
#selector(NotificationView.timerFired(_:))
```

**Note :** `self` is for current `ViewController` if you want to set action for another then you need to specify the `class name.method` in your case it is `NotificationView.timerFired`.

Comment: Both are same. I tried both the code before posting the question. I think its swift3.0's bug.   Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5.0, target:self.notificationView, selector: #selector(NotificationView.timerFired(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

Comment: Have you try as Martin R suggested.

Answer (score 1):

I try the following code and **NotificationView.timerFired** is triggered:

```
class NotificationView {
  @objc func timerFired(_ timer: Timer) {
    print("Timer Fired")
  }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
  let notificationView = NotificationView()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    Timer.scheduledTimer(
      timeInterval: 5.0, 
      target:self.notificationView, 
      selector: #selector(NotificationView.timerFired(_:)), 
      userInfo: nil, 
      repeats: false
    )

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below worked for me (in playground/swift 3) :

```
class SomeClass {

    @objc public func timerFired(_ timer: Timer) {
        print("Timer Fired")
    }
}

let s = SomeClass()

Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5.0, target:s, selector: #selector(s.timerFired(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: false).fire()
//This also will work
//Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5.0, target:s, selector: #selector(SomeClass.timerFired(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: false).fire()
```